# Bash add text on line script

Tags: shell-script, sed, variable-substitution

Trying to get my script to work but it won't work. Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
a="* * * * * /home/server/scripts/check.sh"
b="0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/checks2.sh"
sudo sed -i '28s/^/'$b'\n/' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
sudo sed -i '28s/^/'$a'\n/' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
exit
```

How to add variable into it? I just got `sed -e incomplete 's' command`.

Comment: is this meant to add two lines to root's crontab?  or change an existing line twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add text on line before match](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281873/add-text-on-line-before-match)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the `sed` command:

- the variables `$a` and `$b` are not quoted, which makes the shell pass their *parts* to `sed` as several parameters, and
- the delimiter for the substitution, `"/"`, is also found in the values of `$a` and `$b`.

`sed` accepts other delimiters, such as comma and percent.  You are using comma, but percent is not used.  If you revised the script to

```
#!/bin/bash
a="* * * * * /home/server/scripts/check.sh"
b="0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/checks2.sh"
sudo sed -i '28s%^%'"$b"'\n%' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
sudo sed -i '28s%^%'"$a"'\n%' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
exit
```

or even

```
#!/bin/bash
a="* * * * * /home/server/scripts/check.sh"
b="0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/checks2.sh"
sudo sed -i "28s%^%$b\n%" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
sudo sed -i "28s%^%$a\n%" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
exit
```

that would solve both problems.