# add text on line before match

Tags: shell-script, sed, cron

Trying to add text on the line before that it find the match (updateKey.sh) in this case, but won't get it to work.
Here is my crontab file that the script adds the line to

```
0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh
0 05 * * * /home/server/scripts/updateKey.sh
```

The first line "CCgenerator.sh" is sometimes deleted but it has to look like that. And here is the script that adds that line.

```
#!/bin/bash
CCgenerator="0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh"
updateKey="0 05 * * * /home/server/scripts/updateKey.sh"


if ! sudo grep -q "$CCgenerator" /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root; then
    echo "Adds CCgenerator.sh"
    sudo sed -i '/\$updateKey/i $CCgenerator' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
    else
    echo "CCgenerator.sh found"
fi
exit
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Do you mean sudo sed -i '/\"($updateKey.sh)"/i "($CCgenerator)" ' /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

Comment: (1) I don’t see why don_crissti suggested braces; they don’t seem to be needed in this case. (2) A simplistic answer would be `sed -i "/$updateKey/i $CCgenerator"`, but that will fail because `$updateKey` contains slashes.  `sed` will see `"/0 05 * * * /home/server/scripts/updateKey.sh/i 0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh"`, which will fail.  You should be able to handle the slashes with `sed -i "\|$updateKey|i $CCgenerator"` (using a character that doesn't appear in `$updateKey`), but this will still have a problem with the asterisks, and I’m not sure how to handle them easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash add text on line script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281765/bash-add-text-on-line-script)

Comment: Thank you for showing your source file. What is the transformed result you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cron edit purpose l0b0 answer is the best way, to fix your script you have to:

- escape dots and asterisk in your search key (`updateKey`)
- use alternative separator in `sed` (I choose `%`)
- double quotes around sed expression (you want your bash variables resolved)

---

```
#!/bin/bash
CCgenerator="0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh"
updateKey="0 05 \* \* \* /home/server/scripts/updateKey\.sh"

if ! grep -q "$CCgenerator" cron; then
    echo "Adds CCgenerator.sh"
    sed -i "\%$updateKey%i $CCgenerator" cron
else
    echo "CCgenerator.sh found"
fi
exit
```

Comment: I'm not able to run "cron" that's why I run the file /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than update the crontab directly you'll want to use a [standard mechanism to add a cron job](https://askubuntu.com/a/58582):

```
line="* * * * * /path/to/command"
(crontab -u userhere -l; echo "$line" ) | crontab -u userhere -
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't edit a crontab file directly.  Use the `crontab` command, that's what it's for.
2. Don't use `sudo` multiple times in a script.  Run the entire script with sudo.
3. Quote your variables and strings properly.  Single-quotes around literal strings, Double-quotes for variable etc interpolation.
4. You should be grepping for fixed strings rather than regular expressions, so use `grep -F`.  Otherwise the `*`s in the patterns will be interpreted as "zero or more spaces".
5. You don't need `exit` at the end of a script unless you want to set a specific return value (which you aren't doing).  The script is going to exit at the end anyway.
6. You're grepping for the existence of the `CCgenerator.sh` crontab entry, but then just assuming that the `updateKey.sh` exists.
7. More importantly, why do you even care where in the crontab the `CCgenerator.sh`  rule is?  It works just as well if it's at the beginning or end of the file.  So you don't even need to search for `updateKey.sh` anyway.

This should address all of the above points:

```
#! /bin/bash
CCgenerator='0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh'

if ! crontab -u root -l | grep -Fq "$CCgenerator" ; then
    echo 'Adding CCgenerator.sh'
    # append "$CCgenerator to end of root's crontab
    (crontab -u root -l ; printf '%s\n' "$CCgenerator") | crontab -u root
else
    echo 'CCgenerator.sh found'
fi
```

If you really don't don't want to run the entire script with `sudo` then add `sudo` before every use of the `crontab` command.

And if you actually care where the `CCGenerator.sh` line is relative to the `updateKey.sh` line then:

```
#! /bin/bash
CCgenerator='0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh'
updateKey='0 05 \* \* \* /home/server/scripts/updateKey\.sh'

if ! crontab -u root -l | grep -Fq "$CCgenerator" ; then
    echo 'Adding CCgenerator.sh'
    crontab -u root -l | sed -e "\:$updateKey: i\
$CCgenerator
" | crontab -u root
    else
    echo 'CCgenerator.sh found'
fi
```

This will, however, fail to do anything if `$updateKey` isn't in the `crontab`.  A better version would grep for `$updateKey`, runthe `sed` command to insert `$CCgenerator` if it existed, otherwise use something like the subshell with `crontab -u root -l ; printf ...` I used to append `$CCgenerator` to the end of the crontab.

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
CCgenerator='0 06,18 * * * /home/server/scripts/CCgenerator.sh'
updateKey='0 05 \* \* \* /home/server/scripts/updateKey\.sh'

# we're going to use `crontab -u root -l` multiple times, it's
# best to just fetch it once and store it in a variable.
rootcrontab="$(crontab -u root -l)"

if ! grep -Fq "$CCgenerator" <<<"$rootcrontab"; then
    if grep -q "$updateKey" <<<"$rootcrontab" ; then
        echo 'Inserting CCgenerator.sh'
        echo "$rootcrontab" | sed -e "\:$updateKey: i\
$CCgenerator
" | crontab -u root
    else
        echo 'Appending CCgenerator.sh'
        printf '%s\n' "$rootcrontab" "$CCgenerator" | crontab -u root
    fi
else
    echo 'CCgenerator.sh found'
fi
```

NOTE: `$updateKey` already has its `*` characters escaped, so we don't need to use `grep -F`.

Comment: BTW, `man crontab` mentions that it uses stdin if you give it a filename of `-`.  It also uses stdin if you don't give it a filename at all, but this is undocumented....at least in the version of `crontab` I'm using (vixie cron 3.0pl1 on debian sid).  Add the `-` pseudo-filename if it doesn't work for your version of `crontab`.