# find and replace with sed not working

Tags: sed

I am trying to change a line in a file without `-t` to include it;

`sudo sed -i.bak 's|create  cifs.spnego    * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k|create  cifs.spnego    * * /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k|g' /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf`

However when I `cat` the file, nothing has changed

Comment: Does the original file contain literal `*` characters that you're trying to match?  Those will need escaping, as in [this similar problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281906/90751).

Comment: yes, above is the line in the file verbatim

Answer (score 0):

`sudo sed -i.bak 's|create  cifs.spnego    \* \* /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall %k|create  cifs.spnego    \* \* /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall -t %k|g' /etc/request-key.d/cifs.spnego.conf`

Seems to have done the trick